# How to add commas when using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `adding_commas()` which adds commas at 1000s place and returns the number in string format. These commas seem to work in the `console.log()`, but not on the webpage when i use

```js
document.getElementById('totalbudgets').innerHTML = adding_commas(totalbudget);
```

I need the numbers with comma format on the page as well. Kindly help.
Here is the `adding_commas` function as well.

```js
function adding_commas(x){
    x=x.toString();
    var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
    var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
    if(otherNumbers != '')
        lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
    var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
    console.log(res); return res;
}
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - It's three backticks (`\``) and not a single quotes (`'`) for a code block ;)

Comment: Can you share your HTML for better understanding of the issue?

Comment: Please make this an actual [mcve] because that should definitely work: https://jsfiddle.net/efwx7ph8/

Comment: check console.log(document.getElementById('totalbudgets')) and console.log(totalbudget)

Comment: I dont get any console message with console.log(document.getElementById('totalbudgets'))

Comment: @myesteriousbot, Kindly check the answer I posted.

Comment: can you share the HTML code of `totalbudgets` block ?

Comment: ```

<div class="card bg-success mb-2">
                     <div class="card-body">
                        <h4>Total Budget</h4>
                        <span data-tooltip="Custom tooltip on the right." data-tooltip-position="right">&#9432;</span>
                        <div id="totalbudgets"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div> 

```
Here is the HTML . It outputs the numbers correctly, but commas missing

Answer (score -1):

try this single line solution

```
function adding_commas(x){
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: His output is working properly, the issue is not with his function, instead something else.